# AJAX jquery form submitting an error message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to a Jquery Ajax contact form from treehouse's blog [Click here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form) i have tried to edit the form slight by removing the 'message field'. From the HTML and JS

I am receiving an error message after submitting my details in the form. [Code pen link](http://codepen.io/lybstoretwo/pen/KpbQYm)

Below is a snippet of my code.

**HTML  :**

```
<form id="ajax-contact" class="main-contact submit-fade ajax-form" action="register.php" method="POST">
    <ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-2 hide-form">
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

**JS :**

```
var form = $('#ajax-contact');
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

$(form).submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        //$('#message').val('');
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }
    });

});
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "hello@example.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

Comment: The `for` attribute on labels needs to match the `id` of the control it relates to. Don't duplicate the label in the `placeholder`.

Comment: *I am receiving an error message* — Why not tell us what the error message says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all message variables and conditions from php file.
Your code look like this:

```
<?php


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
    $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);


    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "hello@example.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";


    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved the error ("Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.") by setting read/write permission on /volume1/web/

Synology support response: "After checking with our developer, normally, using the PHP mail function won't need the write permission, and not sure why your website needs it.

Furthermore, please be aware that giving R/W permission could allow someone to write or even overwrite files in /web folder, or the subfolders."